# Check the unicity of the concatenation of two columns

Tags: sql, concatenation, oracle-sqldeveloper, create-table, unique-constraint

I have a probleme with this :

```
    CREATE TABLE Nageurs
    (NrLigue CHAR(14)
         CONSTRAINT CpNageurs PRIMARY KEY,
    Nom VARCHAR2(20) check (Nom is not null),
    Prenom VARCHAR2(20) check (Prenom is not null),
CONSTRAINT unique_farsiss UNIQUE(nom||prenom),  /// HERE !
    );
```

The problem is from the last line, i try to check if the concatenation of nom and prenom is unique but it seems that '||' and 'CONCAT' don't work when they're used in a CREATE TABLE. 
How can i do it please ?

Comment: What's the purpose? Give example of valid/invalid Nom and Prenom combinations.

Comment: I just have to check if the combinations are unique . For example if we enter "Henry" as nom and "Marc" as prenom, the concatenation of those will be "HenryMark" and this combination must be unique in TABLE Nageurs.

Comment: But i don't know how to concatenate them in the create table